# Cannot get items to display on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am attempting to use JavaScript on a canvas.  the object is to have mouse display in the holes.  I cannot get them to display.  I have tried to alot of methods. I have been working on this for almost a month!  At this point I just want them to work inside of any browser. I know its something that I am missing to call the drawings to html.  Please any help will be grateful.

I have tried quackit, w3schools, develops.mozilla. The only things that displays is the canvas.  I usually code with an index.html css and js page not everything on one page.  I took the css page out to help with debugging.

Well anything will help thank you

```js
var pic = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
if (pic.getContext) {
  var drawMouse = pic.getContext("2d");

  var drawMouse = function(mouseFaceX, mouseFaceY) {
    //ears
    fill(97, 65, 10);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX + 19, mouseFaceY - 28, 30, 30);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX - 18, mouseFaceY - 28, 30, 30);

    //inner ear
    fill(242, 102, 148);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX + 19, mouseFaceY - 28, 20, 20);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX - 18, mouseFaceY - 28, 20, 20);

    //face
    fill(97, 65, 10);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX, mouseFaceY, 49, 60);

    //eyes
    fill(255, 255, 255);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX + 12, mouseFaceY - 7, 15, 20);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX - 12, mouseFaceY - 7, 15, 20);

    //pupils
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX + 12, mouseFaceY - 7, 10, 10);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX - 12, mouseFaceY - 7, 10, 10);

    //highlights
    fill(255, 255, 255);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX + 14, mouseFaceY - 9, 5, 5);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX - 10, mouseFaceY - 9, 5, 5);

    //nose
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX, mouseFaceY + 29, 18, 13);
  };

  var messagedirX = 15;
  var mouseFaceX = 200;
  var mouseFaceY = 165;
  var bgX = 250;


  var draw = function() {
    bgX -= 1;
    //background (at bottom);
    background(bgX, 250, 170);

    //holes
    fill(71, 68, 71);
    ellipse(200, 200, 90, 25);
    ellipse(310, 286, 90, 25);
    ellipse(317, 128, 90, 25);
    ellipse(87, 102, 90, 25);

    //ears
    fill(97, 65, 10);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX + 19, mouseFaceY - 28, 30, 30);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX - 18, mouseFaceY - 28, 30, 30);

    //inner ear
    fill(242, 102, 148);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX + 19, mouseFaceY - 28, 20, 20);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX - 18, mouseFaceY - 28, 20, 20);

    //face
    fill(97, 65, 10);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX, mouseFaceY, 49, 60);

    //eyes
    fill(255, 255, 255);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX + 12, mouseFaceY - 7, 15, 20);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX - 12, mouseFaceY - 7, 15, 20);

    //pupils
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX + 12, mouseFaceY - 7, 10, 10);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX - 12, mouseFaceY - 7, 10, 10);

    //highlights
    fill(255, 255, 255);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX + 14, mouseFaceY - 9, 5, 5);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX - 10, mouseFaceY - 9, 5, 5);

    //nose
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    ellipse(mouseFaceX, mouseFaceY + 29, 18, 13);


    //message
    messagedirX -= 1;
    textSize(38);
    text("Hello Ralph!!!", messagedirX, 300);

    //all the mice
    drawMouse(87, 70);
    drawMouse(311, 254);
    drawMouse(316, 93);
  };


}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1700" height="800" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing basic stuff like to get the drawing going..
1. To draw anything you need to beginPath(), provide information and close it to restart from other point.
2. I don't know if any eclipse method on canvas so you will have to define that. In below code I have an example of how to draw an oval shape on canvas.

Take lead from this example and may be you can get to where you want to go. My recommendation is start on smaller pieces and then add more to it.

```js
var pic = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var drawMouse = pic.getContext("2d");

drawMouse.save();
// translate context
drawMouse.translate(pic.width / 2, pic.height / 2);
// scale context horizontally
drawMouse.scale(2, 1);
drawMouse.beginPath();
drawMouse.arc(0, 0, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
drawMouse.restore();
drawMouse.fillStyle = "#8ED6FF";
drawMouse.fill();
drawMouse.closePath();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @spooky has mentioned, you are quite far off the mark.

Looking at the code you provided, my guess is that you're confusing the Processing language with javascript.

To get items to display on canvas you'll need to write javascript.
take a look at the following tips:

1. research the arc() method: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-arcs/
2. here's a general tutorial for paths: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-paths/

Alternatively, you can attempt to use ProcessingJS, which converts from Processing to javascript: http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html but this may confuse you further - I would recommend spending an hour reading the first two links and then building out some simple examples such as the one @spooky provided.